# AcceptTcpClientAsync doesn't wait for the response

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm trying to write a console application

```
        _mainListener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000));
        _mainListener.Start();

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                TcpClient client = await _mainListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                client.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;

                WaitForData(client);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StartListening();
        }
```

Application is being terminated immediately just after the

```
TcpClient client = await _mainListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
```

I know there is no problem with connecting to port 5000 cause AcceptTcpClient works unlike the Async method, it goes to WaitForData with a valid response. I need to use Async one cause the app'll connect to multiple ips. What am i missing?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: if the AcceptTcpClient works - it would suggest logic error, as the non async code still will accept more than one connection.

Comment: Yes it accepts multiple connections but waits for the one connection to be closed before it continues to work on the other

Comment: So you hand off to a thread.. and go back round the loop. Even your way its the same, for the most part..

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword causes execution of your method to stop, and the remainder of the method will continue once a client connects.

However, if this is the only code you're calling from your `Main()` method, then the program will terminate as soon as you get to that line as there's nothing left running.

I don't think you need to use async for what you're trying to do, provided `WaitForData()` is async internally then this code will just go round a loop continuing to accept more clients.

Comment: I need async to connect to multiple ports simulatenously, with the sync method other connections are waiting before the active one is being closed.

Comment: That would only happen if `WaitForData` is sync itself. If it is async or runs sync in a separate thread, this method will carry on round the while loop and accept the next client.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, I've changed `await _mainListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();` to the `await _mainListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().Result;`. This solved the problem, but I don't really feel like blocking a pool's thread. I guess there should be another solution....